# How to find out in which middleware POST to Razor page fails and why

Tags: asp.net, debugging, razor-pages

I created ASP.NET Core Empty web application. Added Razor pages support by hand. I can see rendered page. But POST doesn't get to `OnPost`.

I was trying to find the reason for it. But though it does stop on the first breakpoint it does not on the second and the response is 400 as shown below.

[image: img]

> This page isn’t working
> If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
> HTTP ERROR 400

How can I find out what middleware returns 400 and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 400 status code is not the result of an exception. It's because the underlying MVC framework returned a `BadRequestResult`. 400 denotes a malformed request. It is the default behaviour in Razor Pages during a POST request if the request fails to include a valid request verification token (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification).

Comment: nope, in my case it was gone after I added `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` to `_ViewImports.cshtml`

Comment: Actually, yes. When you enabled tag helpers, you enabled the form tag helper which is responsible for rendering the request validation token value to a hidden field, thus preventing the 400 Bad Request from being returned.